# How to update the content for NCWidgetListViewController

Tags: objective-c

I was trying to write my first Mac OS Today Extension Widget using Xcode 6.
Somehow I figured out how to show the content in the way I wanna.

Here is the problem:
I was trying to refresh the displaying data within the Today-Extension. But I could not find
any example how to do it (especially not for Objective-C).

Can anybody give me a Objective-C code example?

Update: I was looking for a solution similar to reloadData which is used on UITableView

Answer (score 1):

just set *exampleListViewController.contents* to something different than it was before.

It seems NCWidgetListViewController checks if you set it to the same contents again, and then does not refresh its view.